# I'm trying to build a simple currency converter. my function to convert the currency keeps giving me an error

Tags: javascript, angular, currency

I'm getting this error 'The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enumtype.'

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-convert',
      templateUrl: './convert.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./convert.component.css']
    })
    export class ConvertComponent implements OnInit {
      amount = 1;
      from = 'USD';
      to = 'GBP';
      rate = '1.37';
    
      // function for conversion.
      convert(): number {
        return this.amount * this.rate;
      }
    
        
    
      constructor() {}
    
      ngOnInit(): void {}
    }
```

Comment: Your rate is a string..

Comment: Unrelated, `from` is a reserved word in Typescript. You've even used it a bunch of lines earlier. I'd refrain from using it as a variable name.

Comment: It even shows up as blue in the prettyprint here

Comment: What is your question? Please make more clear for your question.

Comment: @Daniel.Wang `error 'The right-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enumtype.'`

Answer (score 0):

Either change `rate = '1.37';` to `rate = 1.37;`
or change
`return this.amount * this.rate;` to `return this.amount * Number(this.rate);`

You should also rename the variable `from` to `convertFrom`, because `from` is a reserved term.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

```
rate = ‚1.37‘
```

This gets interpreted as a string. Write it as

```
rate=1.37
```

Then it should work